# Add UDID to Provisioning profile which is managed by xCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

**Physically device is not present**, **only UDID is.** How am I supposed to add UDID of a Apple Device to an existing provisioning profile.

I certainly can't do it from developer.apple.com (membership account) since it shows managed by xcode and Edit option is disabled.

Seeing several answers on here I went to Window->Devices
+(icon at the bottom). But it is demanding presence of device.

[image]

I might be missing right step.Last option is to recreate the provisioning profile using membership centre.

Comment: why is edit disabled on member center, it seems it is enabled my side and thats how i do it.

Comment: Edit disabled, stating - managed by xcode. Other have had this behaviour if u just check on this.

Comment: post the screenshot please

Comment: You can delete the XCode managed profile and then create your own and import that into XCode, or if you want to distribute the app to someone for testing, create a new distribution profile and use that when you archive the app

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me on Xcode 9.0 when using a provisioning profile managed by Xcode:

- Add the device on the Apple developer site at  https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/ and enter a meaningful name and the UDID
- Delete all previously downloaded provisioning profiles on your local disc at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`

Xcode should then automatically re-download the new provisioning profile that includes the newly added device when needed.